# Need help converting dataset into Columns

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have to compile data into an access database with the final product being an excel spreadsheet which will be used to upload said data into a third party software application.

The database will house medical data which will include Company, Covered Employee, Covered Employee Dependents. The data itself spans 17,000 records.

My dilemma is, one row on the spreadsheet can have up to 255 columns due to the fact that the company, the covered employee and all of their dependents have to all be placed on the same row.

How would I accomplish this? I'm thinking something like this.

group by: employee, dependents and then create a crosstab query from the result set?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Uploading from access is not an option? What is the question here? What have you tried already? Where didn't it work?

Comment: I guess the simple question would be. How do I take the results (rows) of a query and create a new table/query (columns)? Upload has to be excel; just getting started, but wasn't quite sure how to take each of the rows in a dataset and convert them to columns (could be upwards of 100 columns, since there would be multiple rows).

Answer (score 0):

Create your query as a table creation query (query designer, button "Create Table" -> you will be asked to give a name), execute the query: the table will be created. Goto Excel and import that table from access. (Data->import from access).

If it is a recurring job save the query in access. Now you can delete the table after importing it into excel and recreate it anytime with the query. In Excel you can save the import parameters so you can also do it in one click the next time.

Comment: Let me try it this way. I have 1 insured person and that person has 5 dependents. If this is queried out, it will generate 5 rows (each dependent). How do I take those 5 rows and create a new table/query with all 5 rows as the columns in the new table/query? In essence, I would need the following as columns for each dependent so that they are all on one row as opposed to 5: 

Individual SSN (b1) DOB (c1) First Name (a1) Middle Name (a1) Last Name (a1) Suffix (a1) Covered 12 Months (d1) Jan (e1) Feb (e1) Mar (e1) Apr (e1) May (e1) Jun (e1) Jul (e1) Aug (e1) Sep (e1) Oct (e1) Nov (e1) Dec (e1)

Comment: Please read through your comment and imagine reading it without knowledge of what is on your computer: would you get what the poster means by (e1)? I would like to help with programming - but not with solving riddles. Sorry